# log4j2 properties file for a custom appender

Tags: java, log4j2

I created a custom appender and it's not getting called when I run my test.  Here's what the properties look like:

```
name=config
appenders=console, myCustomAppender

appender.console.type=Console
appender.console.name=STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type=PatternLayout
#appender.console.layout.pattern =%d{HH:mm:ss} [%t] %c{1} [%-5level] - %msg%n
appender.console.layout.pattern=%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} [%-5p] (%F:%L) - %m%n

appender.myCustomAppender = com.myCompany.logging.log4j.WindowsEventLogAppender
appender.myCustomAppender.name = WindowsEventLogAppender
appender.myCustomAppender.type = WindowsEventLogAppender

rootLogger.level=info
rootLogger.appenderRefs=stdout, myCustomAppender
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref=STDOUT
```

My appender is called a WindowsEventLogAppender.  Any idea what's wrong with my properties file?  I see the console test messages but none of the messages from my appender.  Right now I'm just doing a System.out.println in my custom appender to verify it's getting called.

BTW, I've found lot's of XML examples out there for log4j2 configurations with custom appenders but none for using a properties file for configuration.

Thanks,
-Mike

Comment: well, why don't you choose loading the xml? It's the default and recommended way. And simple as well. Don't wanna sound condescending, just an oppinion

Comment: I did get it to work with the XML format but we have a lot of components that use .properties configuration files.  I thought keeping the .properties would be the best path forward because I wouldn't have to convert a bunch of .properties files to XML.  Plus it would seem like it should work right?  Otherwise why provide the .properties method.

Comment: @Mike_G please accept my post as an answer if that helped solve your query.

Answer (score 4):

I might be quite late here, but I think my answer can help other people looking for answers. Please accept this as an answer if this is correct!

If you have created a custom appender having annotation like this:

```
@Plugin(name = "MyCustomAppender", category = "Core", 
elementType = "appender", printObject = true)
public final class MyCustomAppenderImpl extends AbstractAppender {
  // other code for the plugin....
}
```

The log4j2 manual about [Configuring Appenders](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Appenders) states that:

> "An appender is configured either using the specific appender plugin's name or with an appender element and the type attribute containing the appender plugin's name"

Meaning the `type` for appender should be Appender Plugin's `Name` attribute value.

Which in above case is **MyCustomAppender** (`appender.identifierName.type=MyCustomAppender`)

So, the Properties file configuration for this to work should be:

> (Note : I have added a stdout(console) appender just to show
> relevance/similarity of usage with OOTB appenders, and 2 example
> usages with RootLogger and a custom logger)

```
# this packages attribute is important, please put comma seperated package(s) to the 
# plugin(s) you have created
packages = com.package.to.your.plugin

# Example: Declare and Define OOTB Console appender, which sends log events to stdout
appender.console.name = stdout
appender.console.type = Console

# Declare and define the custom appender like this
# Note that the "abc" in "appender.abc.type" can be anything
# and the value for "appender.abc.type" should be the same as 
# "Name" attribute value given in custom appender plugin which is "MyCustomAppender"
appender.abc.name=arbitrary_name
appender.abc.type=MyCustomAppender

rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.abc.ref = arbitrary_name    

logger.loggeridentifier.name = com.test.SomeClass
logger.loggeridentifier.appenderRef.stdout.ref = stdout
logger.loggeridentifier.appenderRef.abc.ref = arbitrary_name

# Also note that the value of appenderRef should be the same name given to your 
# appender in properties file, which in this case is "arbitrary_name" (as given above)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the packages property.

Like: packages = com.myCompany

Answer (score 0):

You haven't included the package info

try the below configuration.

```
name=config
appenders=console, myCustomAppender
appender.console.type=Console
appender.console.name=STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type=PatternLayout
#appender.console.layout.pattern =%d{HH:mm:ss} [%t] %c{1} [%-5level] - %msg%n
appender.console.layout.pattern=%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} [%-5p] (%F:%L) - %m%n
appender.myCustomAppender = com.myCompany.logging.log4j.WindowsEventLogAppender
appender.myCustomAppender.name = WindowsEventLogAppender
appender.myCustomAppender.type = WindowsEventLogAppender
rootLogger.level=info
rootLogger.appenderRefs=stdout, myCustomAppender
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref=STDOUT
rootLogger.com.mycompany.example=INFO,STDOUT
```